# Pack 4 digit length number into a two byte char - packed bcd

Tags: c, bcd

I have to send a message where I am supposed to provide lengh of the message as 2 btye packed bcd header.

Suppose if the length is 360 bytes, I should send [01][5E]

Can someone guide me pls.

Thanks.

Comment: [01][5E] is not 360 in packed BCD (or in regular hex, for that matter). Please, elaborate.

Comment: sorry. it is 350(dec) to 01x5E

Comment: that is not what called packed BCD ? [0000 0001] [0101 1110]

Comment: BCD is, as its name suggests, binary-coded decimal - i.e. the four-bit "nibbles" correspond to decimal digits. So, 350 would be [03][50] - possibly a little different if you add the sign and byte order, but you get the idea.

Comment: Yes. now I am clear. I mixed my requirement with the concept. let me rephrase, I want to pack 015E into two bytes as [0000 0001] [0101 1110]

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41041/discussion-between-libadarsh-so-1-0-1-and-maciej-stachowski)

Comment: sorry chat blocked for me. please post here